# Need help deleting node from linked list c++

Tags: c++, linked-list

Hello everyone i'm currently trying to delete a node from my linked list from any position, i can successfully delete the node from the beginning just can't seem to figure out how to delete anything else.

and here's my remove function, any help would be much appreciated.

```
void PartList::removePart(string partNum){

Part * walker = firstPointer;
Part * stalker = NULL;
while (walker != NULL)
{
    stalker = walker;
    if (partNum == walker->partNo)
        break;
    walker = walker->link;
}

    if (walker == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Part Number Not Found..." << endl;
    }
    else {
        if(stalker == NULL){
            cout << "Not Found.."<< endl;
        }
        else {
            stalker->link = walker->link;
        }
    }
    if (firstPointer->partNo == partNum)
    {
        firstPointer = walker;
        walker->link = NULL;
    }
    if (stalker->partNo == partNum)
    {
        stalker = NULL;
        walker->link = NULL;
    }
    walker->link = firstPointer;


        numParts--;
        delete stalker;
        stalker = NULL;
```

}

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: yeah i know about break points and all that good stuff. trust me though i know how hard this community is on people who ask things all willy nilly, so this is my last resort. i'm in a pickle here and not looking for a code answer but maybe just letting me know where my logic is off here because i know i'm close.

Comment: Codes like `if (stalker->partNo == partNum)
    {
        stalker = NULL;
        walker->link = NULL;
    }
    walker->link = firstPointer;` will make burninate themselves.

Comment: step through with your debugger, and watch how variables are changing, period.

Comment: "Here's the error: `walker->link 0x000000000036acd0 {partNo={Error reading characters of string.} description={Error reading characters of string.} ...} Part *`" okay, what did you do to get that error?

Comment: That likely means `walker->link` is not a valid pointer. Maybe it was already deleted.

Comment: the goal with this function is to delete a node. From any point in the linked list, depending on what "partnum" the client sends from their code. I've been stepping through my debugger and am unable to figure it out i'm just asking for an extra pair of coder eyes to look at my function and let me know if something looks funny. and immibis i shouldn't have that in there as it is caused by a separate function, apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write more readable code. It is more complicated than it needs to be. Lets assume that your list is correctly build. Deleting node:

```
Part * walker = firstPointer;
Part * stalker = NULL;

if(walker == NULL){
    cout << "Empty list" << endl;

    return;
}

while (walker != NULL){
    //stalker = walker; //not here!
    if (partNum == walker->partNo){
        if(walker == firstPointer){ //first node
            //do your stuff, delete walker
            ...
            firstPointer = NULL;
        }
        else{
            stalker->link = walker->link;
            //do stuff, delete walker
            ...
         }

        return;
    }
    stalker = walker; //here!
    walker = walker->link;
}

cout << "Part Number Not Found..." << endl;
```

Comment: Thank you. That was extremely helpful, much appreciated.